# Parse BBCode in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, forum, bbcode

I'm writing an app for a forum. I can get the posts as HTML but I need to do lots of custom things with the posts as I'm not displaying it in UIWebView but natively as rich text (custom handling of `[youtube][/youtube]` tags). So I am instead getting the much cleaner BBCode output of the posts.

[This tutorial](http://www.ultramegatech.com/2009/04/creating-a-bbcode-parser/) seems to fit my needs well enough, however there are some obvious problems with it. On is that if the user types mis-formed BBC I get back bad HTML. Leaving out the closing [/b] as an example.

I am thinking I may just need to loop through the outputted HTML and track if there is an unclosed tag at the end, however I was hoping that there might be a better way to parse BBCode on the iPhone.

Also, lastly I know that is probably the wrong approach (outlined above) but every stack overflow question I've found on BBCode parsing has said not to reinvent the wheel and just use an existing PHP library. But, of course, this is an iOS app so I can't use any code written in PHP.

The question is, what is the best way to parse BBCode on iOS (and if there isn't a library or example available then is there a tutorial on writing a good quality one yourself)?

Comment: Hi Freerunnering. Did you discover how to parse BBCode? Thanks!

Comment: @Carlos not really, I got side tracked and didn't finish the app (so didn't need to parse BBC). Though I'm probably going to return to it at some point soon so I may have an update at some point.